# Python - Logging in TWITTER using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Python 3.10 and I am trying to log in on Twitter using Selenium. I am not able to get a hold of the input button to enter my user. Looks like the selenium documentation has changed. I could not find a good example.

```
This is the code I try:



from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys # not sure why this is greyed out

Chrome_driver_path = "C:/Users/osman/OneDrive/Desktop/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Chrome_driver_path)
driver.get("https://www.twitter.com/login")


First_Name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input')
First_Name.send_keys('osman@yahoo.com')

And this is the error I get:
```

executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Chrome_driver_path)

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/div/div/div/main/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[5]/label/div/div[2]/div/input"}
(Session info: chrome=106.0.5249.119)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
Ordinal0 [0x00841ED3+2236115]

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here:

1. As mentioned, `executable_path` has been deprecated. You should use `Service` object instead as following.
2. Very long absolute XPath locators are very breakable. You have to use relative locators.
3. You also have to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` to wait for elements to become clickable before iterating them.
4. And finally `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys` is greyed out since you never used this import in your code. So, it's OK, but this line could be removed to make your code clean.
   The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = 'https://www.twitter.com/login'
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[autocomplete="username"]'))).send_keys("osman@yahoo.com")
```

This is what happens on `www.twitter.com/login` after the above code run, screenshot:
[image]